# verify if each method started with a comment

Tags: javacc

I want to verify if each method `MyFunction()` started with a comment. So I generated a parser by Javacc via the production rules.

extrait of jj file :

```
// here the comments of MyFunction()
  void  MyFunction : {}
{
<begin> <id> "(" (Argument ())* ")" {}
(Statement ()) *
<end>
}

void Argument:{}
{
<STRING> id
<STRING> id
}

void statement () {}
{
..........
}
```

how I can use regular expression to verifiy if existing comments before declaration of `MyFunction()` in program source in input file stream.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is treat comments as special tokens.  Special tokens are not passed on to the parser, but they are accessible from the next regular token.

Suppose comments are special tokens, spaces are skipped, and your input is

```
"/*Floyd*/ /*Ummagumma*/ begin pink() end"
```

The each token has a `.next` pointer (to the right in the picture) and a `.specialToken` pointer (down in the picture). (null pointers not shown.)

```
begin  -->  id    --->   (     -->    )  -->  end ---> EOF 
  |
  V
comment("Ummagumma") 
  |
  V
comment("Floyd")
```

So what you can do is look at the first token of your method. Was it preceded by a special token? And, if so, was that special token a comment?

```
SKIP : { " ", "\n", "\r" }
MORE: { "/*" : IN_COMMENT }
<IN_COMMENT> MORE { ~[] }
<IN_COMMENT> SPECIAL_TOKEN{ <COMMENT: "*/"> }
.
.
.
void  FunctionDefinition : {
    Token firstToken, id;}
{
    firstToken=<begin> id=<id> "(" (Argument ())* ")"
    (Statement ()) *
    <end>
    { if( firstToken.specialToken == null
       || firstToken.specialToken.kind != COMMENT ) 
           System.out.println("Function " +id.image+
                              " is not preceded by a comment!" ) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello MISTER  Theodore Norvell,
Thank you for your help

Comment: How, I can verify if the file is started by comments.  the file is composed by many production rules . thank you

Comment: If comments are the only special tokens, then just check that the `.specialToken` field of the first regular token is not null. Otherwise, what you can do is to start with the first regular token of the file and follow the chain of `.specialToken` links until you reach a null. The `Token` with a null `.specialToken` link will be the first nonskipped token of the file. Check whether it is a comment. Of course this ignores skipped tokens, so it may report that file starts with a comment even if it actually starts with a space (assuming spaces are skipped); I'd guess you are ok with that.